# xmpp entry getType

Tags: android, xmpp, subscription

In my chatting application when one user adds the other person in his/her contact list then the server entry says BOTH subscription, but in my application the code works according to TO/FROM subscription ( as it is before accepting the friend request). 
But when the user logs out once then the code automatically works according to BOTH subscription. What is happening I am not able to get??

ROSTER IS GIVING OLD VALUES WHILE WHEN I CHECK THE ROSTER LISTENER IT IS GIVING ME CORRECT VALUES AT RUNTIME BUT THE NEW ROSTER CHANGES VALUE ARE NOT VISIBLE IN ENTRY.GETTYPE(), whyyyyyy???

Please help me in this matter?

Please have a look on this. ( same but explained more ) - [Logout to add a friend in xmpp smack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13338515/logout-to-add-a-friend-in-xmpp-smack)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Which Library do You use for XMPP? I've used once seperate time the [SMACK API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) and it does actually its job pretty well.
So when using it, You could just manage your contact list with so called Roster object and register a listener for it handle the changes with appropriate code...
Check out also these [tutorials](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/) and [JavaDoc](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/). There is also Google Code Project - [asmack](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/) - for porting it to android.

Comment: I am also using smack library..will check if I can solve the same